# Как реализовать переадресацию на область страницы в ASP.NET MVC в Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect

Есть форма добавление записи, как при перезагрузке страницы отобразить нижнюю область страницы?

Сейчас есть вот такая реализация:

```
public ActionResult CreateReview(GuestbookReview review)
    {
        review.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
        db.GuestbookReviews.Add(review);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return new RedirectResult(Url.Action("Index") + "#post");
    }
```

внизу страницы разместил: div name="#post"

Но данный метод почему-то не работает, никаких действий не происходит...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не `name`, a `id`. И хаштаг не нужен:

`<div id="post" ...`

Comment: Да, все примеры что смотрел все шли с хэштегэм и name=" " )))

Comment: Теперь возник еще вопрос, возможно ли вместо "#post" использовать как пример @Model.Id ?

Comment: @Macro можно: `<div id="<%= Model.Id %>" ...`

Comment: Не совсем понял, вот сейчас у меня есть объекты <div id="CreateComment@(Model.Id)"></div> Попробовал return new RedirectResult(Url.Action("Index") + "#CreateComment@(Model.Id)");

Comment: @Macro `return new RedirectResult(Url.Action("Index") + "#CreateComment" + <variable same as Model.Id in Index view>);`